# 301 not working with child pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have wordpress site that i am redirecting via entries in the htaccess file. The main page redirects work, but the child pages are not correct. Below is a sample redirect from the file.

Redirect 301 /services/additional-background-screening-services/ https://www.inlinereferencecheck.ca/services.html

The above redirect links to https://www.inlinereferencecheck.ca/services.html/additional-background-screening-services/ on the target site

have I configured something wrong? The top level links work fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mod_alias' Redirect to redirect with changing URLs, use mod_rewrite. mod_alias is made for cases where you want to do simple redirects from https://example.com/* to https://example.org/, but keep the local URL structure.

Mod_rewrite allows much more fine tuned control. Change it to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^services/additional-background-screening-services/$ https://www.inlinereferencecheck.ca/services.html [R=301,L]
```

And make sure that you put it before the Block of WP rewrite rules.